# AngularJS Bootstrap-UI Tooltip - How to Configure Options in Controller

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have an angularJS app which is leveraging bootstrap UI.  I'm trying to set up some bootstrap tooltips, which have a large number of configurable elements.  Rather than making my markup significantly larger than I'd prefer, I'd like to push the options into my controller.

The current markup looks something like this:

```
<p tooltip-placement="right" tooltip="{{bic.multipleIncomeTooltip()}}" tooltip-animation="true" tooltip-trigger tooltip-enable="bic.model.borrowers[bic.borrowerIndex()].income.hasMultipleEmployments"></p>
```

I would prefer to push the options for this into my controller, so the markup can be simplified to something like this:

```
<p tooltip-options="bic.incomeTooltipOptions" />
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: you can create your own directive, and put the current markup as a template, then make "tooltip-options" as a default paramter, which bind to a controller variable. Say your directive named "yourTooltip", then your html will be <div your-tooltip="bic.incomeTooltipOptions" /></div>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, create your own directive that uses that markup and then pass all the values you need

**html**

```
<p tooltip-options="tooltipObject"></p>
```

**js**

```
angular.module('app', [])
.directive('tooltipOptions', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        replace: true,
        controller: ['$scope', function($scope) {
        }],
        template: '<p tooltip-placement="tooltipOptions.placement" tooltip-animation="tooltipOptions.animation"></p>',
        scope: {
          tooltipOptions: '='
        }
    }
});
```